# C# FindWindowEx - I Can't Find Teamviewer Panel

Tags: c#, spy++, teamviewer, findwindowex

I have a program running on my PC that controls another machine via TeamViewer. It all works fine except that sending a mouse click requires TeamViewer to be in the foreground. I have code that sends mouse clicks to programs like Notepad where the edit panel is called "Edit." But the TeamViewer panel is called `TV_REMOTEDESKTOP_CLASS` and `FindWindowEx` fails to find its handle.

Here is my code:

```cs
IntPtr handle = WinGetHandle("axie_machine");
if (handle != IntPtr.Zero)
{
    var panel = FindWindowEx(handle, IntPtr.Zero, "TV_REMOTEDESKTOP_CLASS", null);
    PerformRightClick(panel, new Point(200, 200));
}
```

Here is the image of Spy++ showing the details of the panel

[image]

`FindWindowEx` returns 0x000000.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong with `FindWindowEx` and point in the right direction?

Comment: What is `WinGetHandle("axie_machine")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming by `WinGetHandle("axie_machine")`, you're getting the handle of the TeamViewer window using (part of) its title, then, you're actually getting the handle of the top-level window which your target window whose class is "TV_REMOTEDESKTOP_CLASS" is *not* a child of. It is one of its descendants, but not a direct child. There's one parent window in between as you can see here:

[image]

So, change your code to get the parent window of your target "panel" and then use that to get to the target. The code should looks something like the following:

```
IntPtr tvWindowHandle = WinGetHandle("axie_machine");
if (tvWindowHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
{
    var panelParent = FindWindowEx(tvWindowHandle, IntPtr.Zero, "ATL:03B8D350", null);
    if (panelParent != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        var panel = FindWindowEx(panelParent, IntPtr.Zero, "TV_REMOTEDESKTOP_CLASS", null);
        PerformRightClick(panel, new Point(200, 200));
    }
}
```

Note: You might want to double-check the class of the parent window. It was "ATL:03B8D350" in my version of TV but it might be different for you if you're using another version.

Comment: That is brilliant.  Thanks!